# How to declare an attribute with default-value that can be omitted in DTD?

Tags: xml, dtd

After getting to know DTD for XML, I really like the concept and wish to do something as follows:
I want to have the option to declare an attribute or not, so that if its declared, its one of a set of choices x,y,z, and if its not declared, its considered to be of value m.
I tried the following:

```
type (x|y|z) "m"
```

but I got instead (using java that reads the file):

```
The enumerated type list must end with ')' in the "type" attribute declaration.
```

The entire xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
<!ATTLIST item
name ID #REQUIRED
type (type a|type b) "type a"
>]>

<root>
<item name="name1" type="type a" />
<item name="name2" />
</root>
```

If I dont state the type, as the second item, I get the error. I want it to be implied, that if i didnt state it in the xml, the default value is type a.
Also, another (bit) unrelated issue is that I have to declare all my attributes in the ATTLIST, otherwise they produce an error. is there a way to bypass it ? Currently what I do is declare them all with #IMPLIED, but perhaps its not the correct way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value must be one of the options in the enumeration. Just add `m` as an option:

```
type (x|y|z|m) "m"
```

More info: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-attr-defaults

---

The enumerations must be a single [Nmtoken](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#NT-Nmtoken) (name token) so you can't use the spaces in `type a` and `type b`. You could use something like `type_a`, `type-a`, `typeA`, etc.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE root [
<!ELEMENT root (item+)>
<!ELEMENT item (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST item
    name ID #REQUIRED
    type (type_a|type_b) "type_a">
]>
<root>
    <item name="name1" type="type_a"/>
    <item name="name2"/>
</root>
```

Also, all attributes have to be declared for your XML to be valid. I don't think there is any way around that. Declaring them as `#IMPLIED` is correct.

Comment: Sorry for misleading. I did tried what you suggest, where the def-value is one of the options. However, The java, when reading the xml, says the following error I added

Comment: @Bonjo - Can you add the entire attribute declaration? What would be even better is a complete DTD (element and attribute declarations) that reproduce the error.

Comment: my DTD is embedded in xml. I edit the main question and adding it there